# XSLT Failing to Rename Tag with Dash

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-2.0

I have the following XML and I want to rename `ENTINFO_ACCT-TYPE` to `ENTINFO_ACCT_TYPE` (along with many other transformations seen in my XSLT). However, the XSLT fails to rename `ENTINFO_ACCT-TYPE`. I've tried moving it before the `NORMDOC` root tag is added, and it doesn't make a difference. What am I doing wrong? I've been testing everything on [this](https://www.freeformatter.com/xsl-transformer.html) website.

**XML**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<NORMDOC>
   <DOC>
      <DOCID>123456789</DOCID>
      <FI fitype="B" xref="54815594127">
         <FIName>BANK OF FURY, N.A.</FIName>
         <FITIN>987654321</FITIN>
      </FI>
      <OIs>
         <OI xref="54815594128">
            <OIName>BANK OF FURY, N.A.</OIName>
         </OI>
      </OIs>
      <Subjects>
         <Subject stype="PER" xref="54815594140">
            <SubjectFullName type="L">SMITH/JANE/C</SubjectFullName>
            <SubjectLastName type="L">SMITH</SubjectLastName>
            <SubjectFirstName type="L">JANE</SubjectFirstName>
         </Subject>
      </Subjects>
      <TXT>
         <S sid="123456789-SENT-001">Refer to <ENAMEX type="BANKDIV" id="BAN-123456789-000">FCI</ENAMEX>
            <NUMEX type="CASENUM" id="CAS-123456789-001">Case # FRD-123</NUMEX>.</S>
         <S sid="123456789-SENT-075">For assistance contact <ENAMEX type="BANK" id="BAN-123456789-323">BANK OF FURY</ENAMEX> Law Enforcement Liaison at <IDEX type="PHONE" id="PHO-123456789-324">000-000-0000</IDEX> or <CYBEX type="EMAIL" id="EMA-123456789-325">email@bankoffury.com</CYBEX>.</S>
      </TXT>
   </DOC>
   <ENTINFO ID="ACC-123456789-013"
            TYPE="ACCOUNT"
            NORM="333222111000"
            REFID="ACC-123456789-013"
            ACCT-TYPE="CHK"
            MENTION="MI checking account # 333222111000"/>
   <ENTINFO ID="ACC-123456789-027"
            TYPE="ACCOUNT"
            NORM="000111222333444"
            REFID="ACC-123456789-027"
            ACCT-TYPE="UNK"
            MENTION="debit card #s 000111222333444"/>
</NORMDOC>
```

**XSLT (code to rename in last section)**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:template match="/NORMDOC">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="DOC"/>
    <ENTINFO>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="ENTINFO"/>
    </ENTINFO>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="*">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="TXT">
    <RAW_TXT>
        <xsl:value-of select="."/>
    </RAW_TXT>
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="S">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="*" mode="extra"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="*" mode="extra">
    <xsl:element name="{name()}_{@type}">
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="ENTINFO">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:for-each select="@*">
            <xsl:element name="ENTINFO_{name()}">
                <xsl:value-of select="." />
             </xsl:element>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="/">
  <NORMDOC>
    <xsl:apply-templates/>
  </NORMDOC>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates/>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="NORMDOC/ENTINFO/ENTINFO/ENTINFO_ACCT-TYPE">
        <ENTINFO_ACCT_TYPE><xsl:apply-templates/></ENTINFO_ACCT_TYPE>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Expected (abbreviated)**

```
<NORMDOC>
   <DOC>
       ...
   </DOC>
   <ENTINFO>
      <ENTINFO>
         <ENTINFO_ID>ACC-123456789-027</ENTINFO_ID>
         <ENTINFO_TYPE>ACCOUNT</ENTINFO_TYPE>
         <ENTINFO_NORM>000111222333444</ENTINFO_NORM>
         <ENTINFO_REFID>ACC-123456789-027</ENTINFO_REFID>
         <ENTINFO_ACCT_TYPE>UNK</ENTINFO_ACCT-TYPE>
         <ENTINFO_MENTION>debit card #s 000111222333444</ENTINFO_MENTION>
      </ENTINFO>
   </ENTINFO>
</NORMDOC>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Couldn't you just change:

```
<xsl:template match="ENTINFO">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:for-each select="@*">
            <xsl:element name="ENTINFO_{name()}">
                <xsl:value-of select="." />
             </xsl:element>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

to:

```
<xsl:template match="ENTINFO">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:for-each select="@*">
            <xsl:element name="ENTINFO_{translate(name(), '-', '_')}">
                <xsl:value-of select="." />
             </xsl:element>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: I did not know you could do that, thank you. However, why does my original code not work?

Comment: A template can match only nodes that exists in the input, not nodes you created in the XSLT itself (unless you do the transformation in two passes). You could add a template matching `@ACCT-TYPE`  but then you would have to also apply templates to all attributes of `ENTINFO` instead of processing them by `xsl:for-each`.